# How to decompose the problem with overlapping blocks?

Tags: linear-programming, reference-request, decomposition

If the original problem contains the diagonal block structure property or other specific properties then we can apply column generation or other decomposition algorithms to solve it.

However, if the problem with overlapping blocks (for example, a variable appears into two more blocks) instead of diagonal block. How could we use decomposition algorithms to solve it? Is any related literature recommended?

Comment: Search for *Lagrangian decomposition*, which introduces copies of variables for this purpose.

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks for sharing. I'll check it.